# Conditional Formatting for Custom Visual in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Generally, Can we use conditional formatting for custom visual (especially KPI Grid) in Power BI ?

This subject is critical, I am waiting yours recommends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings for a custom visual are determined by its developer. You would need to consult the custom visual documentation for the settings available to that custom visual.